# Django Admin Validation for Inline ModelAdmin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am using Tabular Inline for my admin page in which for an instruction there could be multiple scrap_code and event_code. But one scrap_code or event_code cannot have multiple instructions.
I have made scrap_code and event_code throughout the table so that they cannot be duplicated.

My admin.py

```
class InstructionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ ScrapEventInstructionMapInline, ]
    fields=('name',)
    form = InstructionMapForm
```

I need to show the users an alert when they try to enter event_code or scrap_code which already exists.
But the problem is **even if we have data** instruction, s_code and e_code are **coming as None**

My forms.py file:-

```
class InstructionMapForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        instruction = self.cleaned_data.get('instruction')
        s_code      = self.cleaned_data.get('scrap_code')
        e_code      = self.cleaned_data.get('event_code')

        qs = ScrapEventInstructionMap.objects.all()
        if s_code:
            dup_scrap = list(ScrapEventInstructionMap.objects.filter(scrap_code=s_code).values('scrap_code'))
            if dup_scrap:
                raise forms.ValidationError ('The Scrap Code provided ({}) already exists, kindly edit it or provide another Scrap Code'.format(s_code))

        elif e_code:
            dup_event = list(ScrapEventInstructionMap.objects.filter(event_code=e_code).values('event_code'))
            if dup_event:
                raise forms.ValidationError ('The Event Code provided ({}) already exists, kindly edit it or provide another Event Code'.format(e_code))
```

How to get the data avoiding None? And how to show the alert to users?

Comment: Do not directly call `list()` on queryset it is already _list_.

Comment: Got it but the instruction, s_code and e_ode are coming as None.

Comment: First of all instruction, e_code and s_code are coming as None. Second of all it is not going inside the if condition. When I am entering same event_code or scrap_code it should go inside the loop and raise ValidationError if it already exists

Answer (score 1):

```
class ScrapEventInstructionAdminFormset(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):

    def clean(self):
        forms = [form for form in self.forms if not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE')]
        for form in forms:
            scrap_code = form.cleaned_data.get('scrap_code')
            event_code = form.cleaned_data.get('event_code')
            if form.instance.id:
                scp = SCPInstruction.objects.exclude(id=form.instance.id)
                is_scrap_code_exists = scp.filter(instruction=form.instance.instruction, scrap_code=scrap_code)
                is_event_code_exists = scp.filter(instruction=form.instance.instruction, event_code=event_code)
            else:
                is_scrap_code_exists = SCPInstruction.objects.filter(instruction=form.instance.instruction, scrap_code=scrap_code)
                is_event_code_exists = SCPInstruction.objects.filter(instruction=form.instance.instruction, event_code=event_code)

            if is_scrap_code_exists:
                form.add_error('scrap_code', 'The Scrap Code provided ({}) already exists, kindly edit it or provide another Scrap Code'.format(scrap_code))
            if is_event_code_exists:
                form.add_error('event_code', 'The Event Code provided ({}) already exists, kindly edit it or provide another Event Code'.format(event_code))

        return self.forms
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Again instruction, e_code and s_code are coming as None. If I'm printing

Comment: First of all instruction, e_code and s_code are coming as None. Second of all it is not going inside the if condition.
When I am entering same event_code or scrap_code it should go inside the loop and raise ValidationError if it already exists

Comment: what is the attribute name for ScrapEventInstructionMap in InstructionMap Model.

Comment: Actually I have used proxy model inheritance for Instruction model. Then ScrapEventInstructionMap with instruction a ForeignKey to Instruction table with scrap_code and event_code.
For admin I have used InlineModelAdmin where I've used TabularInline.

Comment: is scrap_code and event_code are the columns of the InstructionMap?

Comment: Okay I'll add those in my question. Please hold on for a min... I'll give my models

Comment: I've updated the question with model... ScrapEventInstructionMap has 3 fields. instruction which is a ForeignKey to Instruction table. And other 2 fields are scrap_code and event_code

Comment: in the Instruction Form u are trying to  accessing ScrapEventInstructioMap fields?

Comment: Exactly brother. Within Instruction I am adding scrap_code and event_code using TabularInline... But to give users an alerts for duplicate scrap_code or event_code for instructions, I am using form. Where I am getting values as None even if I have values...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204729/discussion-between-basavaraju-us-and-learner).